# Non intersect address in Range

Tags: vba, excel

I have two ranges `A2:E2` and `B1:B5`. Now if I perform intersect operation it will return me `B2`. I want some way through which I can get my output as `B2` to be consider in any one range either `A2:E2` and `B1:B5`. i.e if there is a repeated cell then it should be avoided.

**Expected output :**

`A2,C2:E2,B1:B5`

OR

`A2:E2,B1,B3:B5`

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
    Dim aCell As Range, FinalRange As Range

    Set Rng1 = Range("A2:E2")
    Set Rng2 = Range("B1:B5")

    Set FinalRange = Rng1

    For Each aCell In Rng2
        If Intersect(aCell, Rng1) Is Nothing Then
            Set FinalRange = Union(FinalRange, aCell)
        End If
    Next

    If Not FinalRange Is Nothing Then Debug.Print FinalRange.Address
End Sub
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
$A$2:$E$2,$B$1,$B$3:$B$5
```

**EXPLANATION**: What I am doing here is declaring a temp range as `FinalRange` and setting it to `Range 1`. After that I am checking for each cell in `Range 2` if it is present in `Range 1`. If it is then I am ignoring it else adding it using `Union` to the `Range 1`

**EDIT** Question was also cross posted [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/thread/e84dc168-d98d-4fd1-9e1b-c9a983aac27b)

Answer (score 3):

From my article [Adding a "Subtract Range" method alongside Union & Intersect](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_2974-Adding-a-Subtract-Range-method-alongside-Union-Intersect.html)

This code can be used to

- Subtract the intersect of one range from a second range
- Return the *anti-union* of two separate ranges (ie exclude only cells  that intersetc)

I use this code in [Mappit!](http://www.experts-exchange.com/A_2613.html) to indentify hidden cells (ie `Hidden Cells = UsedRange - SpecialCells(xlVisible)`).

While this code is relatively lengthy it was written to be very quick on larger ranges, avoiding cell loops

```
 Sub TestMe()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = [a2:e2]
Set rng2 = [b1:b5]
MsgBox RemoveIntersect(rng1, rng2) & " " & rng2.Address(0, 0)
End Sub

Function RemoveIntersect(ByRef rng1 As Range, ByRef rng2 As Range, Optional bBothRanges As Boolean) As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Dim lCalc As Long

    'disable screenupdating, event code and warning messages.
    'set calculation to Manual
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        lCalc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    'add a working WorkBook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add(1)
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets(1)

    On Error Resume Next
    ws1.Range(rng1.Address).Formula = "=NA()"
    ws1.Range(rng2.Address).Formula = vbNullString
    Set rng3 = ws1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16)
    If bBothRanges Then
        ws1.UsedRange.Cells.ClearContents
        ws1.Range(rng2.Address).Formula = "=NA()"
        ws1.Range(rng1.Address).Formula = vbNullString
        Set rng3 = Union(rng3, ws1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16))
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rng3 Is Nothing Then RemoveIntersect = rng3.Address(0, 0)

    'Close the working file
    wb.Close False
    'cleanup user interface and settings
    'reset calculation
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        lCalc = .Calculation
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: +1.  I followed the link and then followed the link to the routine to find locked cells.  Good stuff.